# Adobe Animate CC Javascript - start animation everytime it becomes visible

Tags: javascript, animation, actionscript, adobe

I have an Adobe Animate CC animation in the middle of the page that I want to play from the start every time it scrolls into view - both on the down scroll and up scroll - basically anytime it comes into view.  The code below (which I pasted in the 1st frame of my animation) works for starting the animation once it becomes visible - but not for restarting it again if you scroll past it then scroll back up...   Can this be modified to do that?

```
// stop main timeline
this.stop();

// check timeout handle
var chkTimer;

// only check visibility when scrolling has stopped
function scheduleVisCheck() {
clearTimeout(chkTimer);
chkTimer = setTimeout(checkCanvasVis, 250);
}

// play main timeline when canvas has scrolled (vertically) into view
function checkCanvasVis() {
var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
if (rect.top >= 0 && rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight)) {
window.removeEventListener("scroll", scheduleVisCheck);
exportRoot.play();
    }

} 

// hook event listener to window scrolling
window.addEventListener("scroll", scheduleVisCheck);

// just in case canvas starts already visible
checkCanvasVis();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received some additional help and my original code was modified as follows and now works as needed...

```
// stop main timeline
this.stop();

// check timeout handle
var chkTimer;
var inview = false;

// only check visibility when scrolling has stopped
function scheduleVisCheck() {
clearTimeout(chkTimer);
chkTimer = setTimeout(checkCanvasVis, 10);
}

// play main timeline when canvas has scrolled (vertically) into view
function checkCanvasVis() {
var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
if (rect.top >= 0 && rect.top <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) -150 || (rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) && rect.bottom > 150)   ) {
    if (inview == false) exportRoot.play(0);
inview = true;
    } else {
    inview = false;
}
}

// hook event listener to window scrolling
window.addEventListener("scroll", scheduleVisCheck);

// just in case canvas starts already visible
checkCanvasVis();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the algorithm to make it work again when it scrolls out then it comes back.
So try this:

```
var isOnStageFlag:Boolean = false ;
// play main timeline when canvas has scrolled (vertically) into view
function checkCanvasVis() {
   var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
   if(isOnStageFlag == false) {//The rect is still out of view
       if (rect.top >= 0 && rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight)) {
       //Dont remove this Listener > window.removeEventListener("scroll",scheduleVisCheck);
           exportRoot.play();
           isOnStageFlag = true ;//Set this flag to prevent above lines to call again
       }
    }
    else {
        if (rect.bottom  < 0 || rect.top > (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight)) {//You have to recheck this line of code. I wanted to control the animation if goes out of the stage to re activate your first code again
            exportRoot.stop();//Make better performance depends on you animation. because the animation is not on the stage any more
            isOnStageFlag = false ; //Now get ready for animation to back into stage
        }
    }
}
```

I write my description on the code. the checkCanvasVis changed and new variable named isOnStageFlag created.

Good luck

Comment: Thank you for this - but does that code you posted replace a certain part of the code I have? or replace all of it, etc?

Comment: You have to replace the checkCanvasVis() function with mine and add the isOnStageFlag variable to.

Comment: Sorry I could never get your solutions to work - but thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem. My pleasure.